Flutter: How to make suffixIcon go after input in InputDecoration?
I want to display several inputs with some text in between to get the coefficients to a cubic equation like this:
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: <InlineSpan>[
      WidgetSpan(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 32),
              child: const IntrinsicWidth(
                child: TextField(
                    maxLines: null,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        isDense: true, contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0))),
              ))),
      const WidgetSpan(child: Text("x^3 + ")),
      WidgetSpan(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 32),
              child: const IntrinsicWidth(
                child: TextField(
                    maxLines: null,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        isDense: true, contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0))),
              ))),
      const WidgetSpan(child: Text("x^2 + ")),
      WidgetSpan(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 32),
              child: const IntrinsicWidth(
                child: TextField(
                    maxLines: null,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        isDense: true, contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0))),
              ))),
      const WidgetSpan(child: Text("x + ")),
      WidgetSpan(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 32),
              child: IntrinsicWidth(
                child: TextField(
                    controller: controller,
                    maxLines: null,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          onPressed: click,
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.done_outline_rounded),
                          splashColor: Colors.green,
                          tooltip: "Save equation"),
                    )),
              ))),
    ],
  ),
);
}

I am not sure if this is the way to do it. Anyway, I also need to add a button at the end of this input. Currently it looks like this:

I wonder if there is a way to make this icon go after the underscore not above it? Thanks in advance.

how about using Column

Could you please give an example of how I can use it here?

I was able to find a workaround:
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        children: <InlineSpan>[
         ....
          WidgetSpan(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 32),
              child: IntrinsicWidth(
                child: TextField(
                  maxLines: null,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    height: 30.0,
    child: IconButton( 
      color: Colors.green,
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: const Icon(Icons.done_outline_rounded),
      splashColor: Colors.green,
      tooltip: "Save equation"),
  )],
);

Now it looks like this:


Try following code. In this I have wrapped both of the fields in Row() with CrossAxisAlignment.Bottom
        const WidgetSpan(child: Text("x + ")),
        WidgetSpan(
          child: IntrinsicWidth(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 32),
                    child: const IntrinsicWidth(
                      child: TextField(
                          maxLines: null,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              isDense: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0))),
                    ),),
                IconButton(
                  visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
                  iconSize: 24,
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Your button click
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.done_outline_rounded),
                  splashColor: Colors.green,
                  tooltip: "Save equation",
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),

